# When I am going to multiply uint32 variable with sint32 variable why I am getting wrong ans?

Tags: c, embedded

```
sint32 MulDiv (uint32 x_value, sint32 y_value, uint32 z_value) {
    sint64 v_Result_value;
    sint64 v_Temp_Val;
    v_Temp_Val = x_value * y_value;
    if (0 == z_value) {
        if(v_Temp_Val >= 0) {
            v_Result_value = MAX_VAL;
        } else {
            v_Result_value = MIN_VAL;
        }
    }
    return v_Result_value;
}
```

If I pass:

- x_value as 4294967295
- y_value as -12

v_Temp_Val become 12, which is not expected.

Comment: What if `v_Temp_Val = (x_value * (sint64)y_value);`?

Comment: ........and what did you pass as z?  Please indent your code clearly to avoid misinterpretation of control flow.

Answer (score 2):

With the expression `x_value * y_value`, the values of `x_value` and `y_value` goes through [Usual Arithmetic Conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), which

> Otherwise, the signedness is different: If the operand with the unsigned type has conversion rank greater or equal than the rank of the type of the signed operand, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type

That is, the value `-12` is "converted" to an unsigned value, and due to how [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (the most common way to handle negative numbers on computers) works the value `-12` is converted to a very large value (`4294967284` more precisely).

Multiplying `4294967295` by `4294967284` result in arithmetic overflow (because it's a 32-bit multiplication with a 32-bit result), but it's well-defined for unsigned integers. However the result will not be what you expect.